# CMIS and Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, cmis

I am looking at CMIS connectivity from one of our internal applications. I know that CMIS is part of (or will be) part of SharePoint, is there a workable C# API (the OpenAPI C# project seems to be in its initial stages)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably talking about Sharepoint 2010 and the difficulties around "[CMIS and SharePoint 2010 details are hard to find](http://cmsreport.com/blog/2009/cmis-and-sharepoint-2010-details-are-hard-find)".

Microsoft provided a CMIS connector with its [Sharepoint 2010 Administrative Toolkit (Download)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=718447d8-0814-427a-81c3-c9c3d84c456e&displaylang=en).

> The CMIS connector for SharePoint
> Server 2010 includes two features:
>
> - The Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS)
>   Consumer Web Part, which can be added
>   to any SharePoint page. This Web Part
>   displays and lets users interact with
>   the contents of any CMIS repository.
> - The Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS)
>   Producer, which allows applications to
>   interact with SharePoint lists and
>   document libraries programmatically by
>   means of the interfaces defined in the
>   CMIS standard.

Please note that you will need Sharepoint Server 2010 - SharePoint Foundation is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a C# implementation of the CMIS API, client-side.
It is [DotCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html).
Open spource and works great.

Be aware that [only a few versions of SharePoint offer CMIS compatibility](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6003155-implement-cmis-for-real).
Also, among a number of CMIS implementations, [SharePoint has the worse](http://cmissync.org/CmisCompat/):

[image: CMIS SharePoint]